# With the priesthood of all believers do we need priest or pastor as church leaders?

Tags: priesthood

The Old Testament talks about Levites as priest and the New Testament talks of priesthood of all believers. But then there is the gift to some as pastors, teachers and evangelists (Eph 4:11) in the New Testament. If all are priest, one can not be singled out and called a priest. Are the church leaders to be called pastors instead? But the pastor is meant to be a shepherd, who leads, guides, protect, and feeds. If so then the name pastor fits them better.
However some congregations consider them as elders or presbyters with the responsibility as teacher. By this is the gift of pastor and the teacher the same for them to be teachers? What then is the suitable name for them to bring their biblical role out clearly?

Comment: May I ask which verse talks of "priesthood of all believers"? And which verse says "pastor is a gift"?

Comment: I think the accepted answer at [How does the Catholic Church understand the priesthood of all believers?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/5255/how-does-the-catholic-church-understand-the-priesthood-of-all-believers) answers this question. The ministerial priesthood is called to a differentiated ministry.